# How to use pass variables in rmarkdown pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm trying to pass variables to rmarkdown report as params but i'm not able to render it in the report
the below one is my code the my_value param is dataframe having only single row

```
---
title
output:
  pdf_document: default

output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
classoption: svgnames
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}

params:
  my_class:"smile"
  my_value: data$percent

--


`r params$my_value` is the total percentage of customers
`r params$my_class` is product which has been doing better
```

Answer (score 2):

The `YAML` header you're using isn't valid.

- `title` tag should finish by `:` and have a value : `title: "test"`
- `output` should only be used once
- finish header with `---`

Try:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
    
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}

classoption: svgnames

params:
  my_class: "smile"
  my_value: NA

---
```

Regarding parameters, you can't directly use `data$percent` as parameter value in `YAML` header.
Knitting is done in a new environment, `data$percent` doesn't exist in it.

In `YAML`, you could use following settings:

```
params:
  my_class:"smile"
  my_value: NA
```

In calling script:

```
# data definition
data <- ...

params <- list(
  my_class = "more smiles",
  my_value = data$percent
)

rmarkdown::render("MyDocument.Rmd", params = params)
```

For more information : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html

Comment: i tried this but still  getting execution Halted.

Comment: ```Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 7, column 1 could not find expected ':' at line 10, column 1
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted```

Comment: See my edit to correct the `YAML` header besides passing variables

Comment: there sometimes can also be YAML and TOML files, the syntax is not what R expects for the file type. Try a clean directory and R project.